# How can "visio" and "novus" be correctly combined to mean "a new vision/perspective"?

Tags: vocabulary, motto, latin-to-english-translation, agreement

What would be a correct way of combining the words *visio* and *novus*? Could I just combine those two or is *visio* + *nova* a better option?

I would like the phrase to mean something like "a new vision/perspective". The idea is to lead people towards a new vision/perspective that could be the start of a behavioural change. It's for a personal training/health intervention (focus on long-term behaviour changes).

Comment: Since _visio_ is feminine, _nova_ fits while _novus_ does not. Remember also that in Latin word endings change according to the grammatical function of the word: depending on the use you want to give the name, you might want to add some "_flavor/movement_": _visione nova_, _novae visionis_, etc.

Comment: Rafael is right, we need a bit more context here. As a title, *Visio Nova* is probably what you want (the nominative case).

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys! I would like the words (or combination) to mean something as: ''a new vision/perspective''. This can be in a broader sense.

Comment: @rbirrus May I asume you want neither to say nor imply anything of the kind of _towards a new vision_, _about the (our) new vision_, _meet the new vision_ or _let us introduce you to this new vision_?

Comment: Exactly, I would not want to indoctrinate someone into ''my new vision'' but the idea is to lead them towards a new vision/perspective that could be the start of a behavioural change.
It's for a personal training/health intervention (focus on long-term behaviour changes).

Comment: @rbirrus I've updated your question to include the information you provided in comments: feel free to make further edits if you'd like.  Just so you know, it's a good idea to include explanatory information like this in the question itself, as comments are more transitory and are often cleaned up when they are no longer needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since *visio* is feminine, *nova* fits while *novus* does not. So:

> Nova Visio

does the trick as well as:

> Visio Nova

But remember that in Latin word endings change according to the grammatical function of the word. Since in the comments you mention that *the idea is to lead* the reader *towards a new vision*. You may want to ad endings:

> Visionem Novam

suggesting that the title is part of a longer sentence, like *ostendam vobis visionem (meam) novam* (I'll show you the/my new vision) or *ad novam visionem* (towards a new vision).

**Visio** has the [meaning](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvisio) of *an idea, conception, notion*, but I suspect it does not mean *vision* in the full modern extent from which *visionary* derives (*the ability to think about or plan the future with imagination or wisdom*, according to Google definition).

Other nouns that might be useful if *visio* doesn't convince  you:

- *Sapientia*: (f.) wisdom. *Sapientia[m] Nova[m]*
- *Prospectus*: (m.) prospect, outlook. *Novus Prospectus* or *Prospectum Novum*